# Binding DatePicker

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

I want to bindBiderectional() DatePicker. Here is what I did

```
@FXMLController("title.fxml")
public class Controller {
@FXML
private DatePicker dp_date_from;
@Inject
private Model model;
...
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
...
dp_date_from.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.dateFromProperty());
...
}
```

Model Class

```
@FlowScoped
public class Model {
private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFrom;

public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFromProperty() {
        return dateFrom;
    }
...
}
```

It throws an error:

```
io.datafx.controller.FxmlLoaderException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

What can be the reason for that?

Error, is thrown in application itself, it doesn't write anything in a console. I've debegged the code, and when it comes to line `dp_date_from.valueProperty...` it goes here for throwing an exception:

```
public <T> ViewContext<T> createByController(Class<T> controllerClass, String fxmlName, ViewConfiguration viewConfiguration, Object... viewContextResources) throws FxmlLoadException {
try {
    Object e = controllerClass.newInstance();
    ViewMetadata metadata = new ViewMetadata();
    FXMLController controllerAnnotation = (FXMLController)controllerClass.getAnnotation(FXMLController.class);
    if(controllerAnnotation != null && !controllerAnnotation.title().isEmpty()) {
        metadata.setTitle(controllerAnnotation.title());
    }

    if(controllerAnnotation != null && !controllerAnnotation.iconPath().isEmpty()) {
        metadata.setGraphic(new ImageView(controllerClass.getResource(controllerAnnotation.iconPath()).toExternalForm()));
    }

    FXMLLoader loader = this.createLoader(e, fxmlName, viewConfiguration);
    Node viewNode = (Node)loader.load();
    ViewContext context = new ViewContext(viewNode, e, metadata, viewConfiguration, viewContextResources);
    context.register(e);
    context.register("controller", e);
    this.injectFXMLNodes(context);
    context.getResolver().injectResources(e);
    Method[] var11 = e.getClass().getMethods();
    int var12 = var11.length;

    for(int var13 = 0; var13 < var12; ++var13) {
        Method method = var11[var13];
        if(method.isAnnotationPresent(PostConstruct.class)) {
            method.invoke(e, new Object[0]);
        }
    }

    return context;
} catch (Exception var15) {
    throw new FxmlLoadException(var15);
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the full stack trace, and identify the line in your code that generates it.

Comment: @James_D, I've updated the post with what I was able to find

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing the cause of the exception, which is in the stack trace. Please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, the error is due to I didn't initialized dateFrom. I've just added this part into Model class

```
public ObjectProperty<LocalDate> dateFromProperty() {
        if(dateFrom == null){
            dateFrom = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        }
        return dateFrom;
    }
```

Thanks to everybody